# kendo mulitselect doesn't works

Tags: kendo-ui, multi-select, kendo-multiselect

I am using **Kendo MultiSelect** as **UIHint** for one of my field.

```
      the entity having the UIHint is like this:

 public class Test 
{
[UIHint("_MultiSelectList")]
[DisplayName("Labels")]
public List<Students> Labels { get; set; }
 }
```

my _MultiSelectList.cshtml is

```
var multiSelectList = Html.Kendo().MultiSelect().Name("empty");
@(
multiSelectList = Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
        .Name(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(""))
        .Placeholder(ViewData.ModelMetadata.GetCustomMetadata().Placeholder)
        .BindTo(new  SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData[fieldId + "_list"], "Value", "Name"))
            .Filter("contains")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = String.Format("width: {0}; ", width) })
    );
}
```

data is not loaded into the control and it is rendered as html

```
     <div class="k-widget k-multiselect k-header" unselectable="on" style="width: 225px;">

<div class="k-multiselect-wrap k-floatwrap" unselectable="on">
    <ul id="Labels_taglist" class="k-reset" unselectable="on" role="listbox"></ul>
    <input class="k-input k-readonly" style="width: 25px" accesskey="" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="Labels_taglist Labels_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false"></input>
    <span class="k-icon k-loading k-loading-hidden"></span>
</div>
<select id="Labels" style="width: 225px; display: none;" name="Labels" multiple="multiple" data-role="multiselect" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false"></select>
<span style="font-family: MS Shell Dlg; font-size: 13.3333px; font-stretc…: absolute; visibility: hidden; top: -3333px; left: -3333px;"></span>
```

What am missing here ???

Comment: Shouldn't you Labels property be an array or a list? Also what is going into the ViewData. Is that getting populated correctly? I guess I am trying to figure out why you have coded this in the way you have.

Comment: oops my mistake List<student> collection, it has Id and Value..our architecture is built that way , all the other controls like dropdown, combobox, Listbox each one has a separate editor template, where we just declare UIHint attribute

Comment: Can you see the information being populated into the ViewData object that you are binding to this control? It also looks like you are not binding the values to the control when it is loaded. Is this by design.

Comment: I can see the data loaded into ViewData

Comment: Is it possible to see a sample project with this in and then I can take a look at it for you. I had a similar issue where values were not being bound correctly as opposed to data selections not being bound.

Comment: I will try to get a sample project

Comment: Thanks. I only ask as it is difficult at the moment to determine what your actual issue is without being able to recreate the conditions accurately.